# How to prevent fixed bottom bar from hiding content

Tags: html, css

I have a fixed div that is covering up content on the bottom of my page when the user scrolls down.  This specifically impacts mobile devices.  I've recreated the problem here: http://codepen.io/bkuhl/pen/LWjXdx

Here's the code from that post:

```
  <div class="main-content">
    Test Content
    <div class="content-suffix">
      Copyright
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="fixed-bottom-bar">
    I'm covering up the Copyright text
  </div>
```

and CSS:

```
.main-content {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 400px;
  background-color: darkgrey;
}
.content-suffix {
  padding-top: 350px;
}
.fixed-bottom-bar {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 1em;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

One approach I've thought about is adding a `[padding|margin]-bottom` to the content-suffix, but in this case my content on the fixed element has a variable length.

**How can I make sure the "Copyright" text isn't covered by the fixed element, keeping in mind the `fixed-bottom-bar` has a variable text length?**

Comment: add a margin-bottom on the content-suffix

Comment: If your footer is dynamic in height, you could try using jquery for getting the  height in runtime, then apply the css also using jquery

Comment: You can pull off a faux fixed footer that leaves room for the footer to be variable height by using a 100vh tall column flex layout and setting the content area to `flex-grow: 1` and `overflow-y: scroll`. Something like this work? http://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/JWyeqW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the footer is simple you can add it at the bottom of the content and make it hidden so it will take space but will not be displayed.

```css
.main-content {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: darkgrey;
}
.content {
   display: flex;
   align-items: flex-end;
   height: 400px;
}

.bottom-bar {  
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}

.bottom-bar.space { 
   visibility: hidden; /* hides the element but keeps it space*/
} 

.bottom-bar.fixed {  
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-content">
    <div class='content'>Test Content</div>

  <div class="bottom-bar space">
    I'm covering up the<br> Copyright text
  </div>
  <div class="bottom-bar fixed">
    I'm covering up the<br> Copyright text
  </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: Ah - So you're saying essentially display it twice, once hidden so it'll never overlap?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the css `calc()` property to achieve this. Add `margin-bottom: calc(/* the values you want to calculate */);` You haven't set the font-size, but the default is 16px. Therefore, you would want to add padding to the bottom of content-suffix that would be 16px + 2em, the total height of the footer. Your final code would be:

```
.content-suffix {
    padding-top: 350px;
    margin-bottom: calc(16px + 2em);
}
```

This would work better if you specified the font-size of the text somewhere. This could be a dynamic value (e.g. 1vw, 1em, etc.) and this would still work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set position to `absolute`, give overflow-y will be more better and calc for your height.

```css
.main-content {
  width: 100%;
  height : calc(100% - 94px) !important;
  background-color: darkgrey;
  overflow-y : auto;
  position:absolute;
}
.content-suffix {
  padding-top: 350px;   
}
.fixed-bottom-bar {  
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  height : 50px;
  right: 0;
  padding: 1em;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-content">
    Test Content
    <div class="content-suffix">
      Copyright
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="fixed-bottom-bar">
    I'm covering up the Copyright text
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have no restriction for using JavaScript, look at below codes:

```js
var x =
  document.getElementsByClassName("fixed-bottom-bar");

document.getElementById("forged-fixed-bottom-bar").style.height = "" + x[0].offsetHeight + "px";
```

```css
.main-content {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 400px;
  background-color: darkgrey;
}

.content-suffix {
  padding-top: 350px;
}

.fixed-bottom-bar {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 1em;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}

#forged-fixed-bottom-bar {
  height: 20px
}
```

```html
<div class="main-content">
  Test Content
  <div class="content-suffix">
    Copyright
  </div>
</div>

<div id="forged-fixed-bottom-bar">
</div>

<div class="fixed-bottom-bar">
  I'm covering up the Copyright text
</div>
```